# When does "e" change to "ё" in plurals?

Tags: множественное-число, фонетика, буква-ё

I've just started learning German, and what strikes me about their plurals is that a word in its plural form can change not only at the end but in the middle as well (die Kopf / die Köpfe, der Stuhl / die Stühle, der Wald / die Wälde).

And then I realized that in Russian, we have, for instance, forms like:

- десна / дёсны
- весна / вёсны
- ведро / вёдра
- бедро / бёдра

My question is whether there's any rule one can memorize for when this is the case in Russian? If not, is there a more or less exhaustive list of such words?

---

**UPD:** For those who claim that this is due to the "ѣ"/"e" change, can you please be more specific? For instance, words that evolved from *рѣпа*, *пѣна*, *лѣто* do not follow this pattern. On the other hand, the word *жена*, which came from *жєна*, does follow this pattern.

**UPD:**  I just realized that this phenomenon extends further than just "ё"/"е". As Dmitry mentioned, we have "ё"/"е" and we actually also have "a"/"о" (заря/зори).

Comment: Это работает и в обратную сторону: `чёрт - черти`, `счёт - счета`, однако для этого есть правило: [Буквы о-ё-е в корнях слов после шипящих](http://russkay-literatura.ru/pravila-pravopisaniya-russkogo-yazyka/599-bukvy-o-yo-e-v-kornyax-slov-posle-shipyashhix.html). Вот еще заумный [материал](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1194-1215.html#1208), может поможет.

Comment: I think it is just vowel reduction. Not all cases of vowel reduction reflected in spelling though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, as Zaliznyak (1967) shows, it is, synchronically, ё>е in the singular not e>ё in the plural. Words like "десна'" are actually "дёсна'" (' for stress), but unstressed ё is not used in Russian (except for very special cases involving certain loanwords, for which Zaliznyak adds a special rule: "convert unstressed ё to ё` (a special symbol unaffected by most rules)" before converting every е that is in stress-caused alternation with ё to ё), so we write "десна". It is the lexical information of every word (or rather, its morphemes) that serves as its actual phonemic form.

Precisely the same thing happens to words containing ё where this letter loses its stress in the oblique cases: "ёж" - "ежа'" (phonemically "ёжа'").

Diachronically, though, it's related to ѣ, which did not alternate to o in t'et situation (where *t* is any hard consonant but ц, and t' is any soft consonant or ж or ш) and *е* which did. However, ѣ later merged with е, and afterwards some analogy processes caused some words with ѣ to gain "alternation" as well, and some words with е to lose it.

Comment: So you claim that all words that have this ё/e are actually should be pronounced (or originally were) with ё? so, "звёзда", "вёсна", "бёдро" - but well, this does not seem right to me

Comment: I've updated the question with explanation why I'm not fully satisfied with ѣ/e explanation.

Comment: @shabunc Underlyingly they are. But then "ё", "е" and "я" are all subject to the same reduction which leads all the three to be pronounced as [и] or [ь] depending on the position of stress. And we show that in writing for ё but don't show that in writing for я because... well, because reasons.

Comment: @shabunc Actually the diachronical claim is: "Alternation to ё under stress happened in XIV if and only if there was no yat' in the word and it has not been a case of special change (like "звезда" which used to have yat')". However, because of the second part it is not quite useful.

Comment: I assume you are referring to [АА Зализняк «Русское именное Словоизменение»](https://imwerden.de/pdf/zaliznyak_russkoe_imennoe_slovoizmenenie_1967__ocr.pdf).  On which pages is the discussion on ё/е?

Comment: Somewhat distributed. See 194 onwards - especially comments on "accentual-positional alternations", of which the only widespread case is е/ё - and then the concise formulation of I.2 rule at 202: "Any е participating in accentual-positional alternation with ё is to be replaced by ё". Then see 246 onwards on the general notion of "conditional view" for justification, although it doesn't directly touch on е/ё. The general logic is "you can easily restore е from ё but not vice versa".

Answer (score 2):

> жена - жёны
>
> звезда - звёзды

[some people say](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B5-%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5.2124709/#post-10635925) that the difference stems from the form of singular with or without the obsolete letter "ѣ - ять", which denoted the vowel "e", so i guess unless one knows where "ѣ - ять" must be present in the singular form it's impossible to derive the plural form logically

Answer (score -2):

It's quite simple: if you have an emphasis changed from other vovwel to `е` it changes to `ё`.

**Examples**

> ведро — вёдра... and other examples from your question

But not here:

> одежда, умение, отец

Comment: Not such simple. What about `беда́-бéды`, `земля́-зéмли`, `перó-пéрья` etc?